# Point of concurrency in triangle using nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Using the tikz manual I've come up with this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0)
    node [pos=0.5] (mpa) {};
\draw (2,0) -- (2,2)
    node [pos=0.5] (mpb) {};
\draw (2,2) -- (0,0)
    node [pos=0.5] (mpc) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (mpb);
\draw (2,2) -- (mpa);
\draw (2,0) -- (mpc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which renders:
[image: concurrency image]

Which is actually close to what I want.  As you can tell from the code, the lines are supposed to go from the vertices to the nodes I placed at the midpoints of the opposite sides.  The tikz manual *implied* that placing nodes in this fashion places them *on the path* rather than *near it*.  Did I misunderstand?

The follow up question is, in reality, I need a node at the point of intersection that is just a circle, i.e. in some manner emphasizing the point of concurrency.  Then, lines from that point to only the vertices.  Maybe it would be simpler to do this using a single node that is a regular polygon?  Please enlighten me.

Comment: Use `coordinate` rather than `node`. Nodes have dimensions and lines are drawn to the nearest border anchor.

Comment: I don't understand the follow-up. You want a circle at the point of intersection of the 3 lines. OK. You want a circle there. Fine. Where does the regular polygon come in? The triangle isn't regular, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The regular polygon came in because I thought that might be the simplest way to put a point in the center since there's an anchor in the center of the node.  I don't have enough space in a comment to illustrate, but using your illustrations and some other stuff from "texample.net" I was able to get what I want.  Now, the bigger problem, a central triangle with equilateral triangles along the edges of the central one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node have a size and lines to them are drawn to anchors on their borders, by default. Adding `draw=red` shows the issue:

[image: issue]

The nodes are centred on the path. The lines are drawn to and from their borders.

To avoid this, replace `node` by `coordinate`:

[image: coordinates]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw=red}]
  \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node [pos=0.5] (mpa) {};
  \draw (2,0) -- (2,2) node [pos=0.5] (mpb) {};
  \draw (2,2) -- (0,0) node [pos=0.5] (mpc) {};
  \draw (0,0) -- (mpb);
  \draw (2,2) -- (mpa);
  \draw (2,0) -- (mpc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) coordinate [pos=0.5] (mpa);
  \draw (2,0) -- (2,2) coordinate [pos=0.5] (mpb);
  \draw (2,2) -- (0,0) coordinate [pos=0.5] (mpc);
  \draw (0,0) -- (mpb);
  \draw (2,2) -- (mpa);
  \draw (2,0) -- (mpc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

I don't really understand the follow-up since I don't know where a regular polygon comes in. To mark the intersection, I'd use the `intersections` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) coordinate [pos=0.5] (mpa);
  \draw (2,0) -- (2,2) coordinate [pos=0.5] (mpb);
  \draw (2,2) -- (0,0) coordinate [pos=0.5] (mpc);
  \draw [name path=frog] (0,0) -- (mpb);
  \draw [name path=toad] (2,2) -- (mpa);
  \draw (2,0) -- (mpc);
  \path [name intersections={of=frog and toad, name=con}, fill=red] (con-1) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mark intersection]